# Does macOS Safari use the same version of WebKit as iOS Safari (assuming the macOS and iOS Safari versions are equal)?

Tags: ios, macos, safari, webkit

For example, does macOS Safari 10.2 use the same version of WebKit as iOS Safari 10.2?

I know that the WebKit revision number included in a release of Safari [isn't publicly available](https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/FAQ#WhatWebKitSVNrevisionisincludedinSafariversionXXX), but if there's a WebKit bug that I know is fixed in macOS Safari 10.2 can I also assume that it's fixed in iOS Safari 10.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no, you cannot assume they are using the same version. Maybe they sometimes match up but thats not a guarantee.

Source: I checked wikipedia for the OS X version of Safari https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history agains my iPads/iPhones versions. They don't match up at all.

- iOS 10.2.1 - Safari 10.0 - WebKit 602.4.6
- iOS 8.1.3 - Safari 8.0 - WebKit 600.1.4

Even if they would, don't you think you should support all sorts of browsers and versions?